# Regex, not include matched part

Tags: java, regex

Is there any possibility to check for match ( which is optional by the way) but then not include it in resulting groups ?

Example:

text:`94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea`
regex: `^[.*\sof]?(.*)$`

then m.group() returns whole match, but i want just "Papua New Guinea"

I tried already sth like that:

```
^(?:*\sof)?(.*)$
```

but with no positive result.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex works:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:.*?\\sof\\s*)?(.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
Taron, Papua New Guinea
```

Note that `m.group()` returns the whole match. To get the first group use `m.group(1)`

Comment: yeah i already had that solution, but was trying to ommit using m.group(1), because then code is more reliable. but still thanks

Comment: If there is a non-optional group in a regex, it **will** be filled. So `m.group(1)` would be equally reliable for this regex as `m.group()`

Comment: one more question what does it mean that it 'will be filled'. I'm not sure what did u mean by that.

Comment: What I meant was group 1 will always be available if this regex matched. So it is safe to call m.group(1) without checking the number of groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try using positive lookbehind

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\bof\\b)(.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea");
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Produces:

```
 Taron, Papua New Guinea
```

Comment: (?<=\bof\b)(.*) that is enough actually but, i still need to make that first not included group optional, and ? raises an error in such an expression:
(?<=\bof\b)?(.*)

Comment: @kolboc - Please check the answer now

Comment: Thanks for trying but still it's impossible to make t optional. 
Example will be when only Papua New Guinea appears in text. Thanks anyway, it seems i have to do that with m.group(1);
Still ty very much for your investment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot (or should not) get anything outside the matching part. So, you just have to include it in the regexp. I think this will work:

```
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(.*\\sof\\s.*,\\s)?(.*)");
    Matcher matcher;
    matcher=pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.group(2);
```

Note: I think you want to set the word "of" as a delimiter, but you were doing it wrong: This regexp:

```
^[.*\sof]
```

means "any character which is not a blank, or an 'o' or an 'f' or any other. Within an interval `[abcd]` definition, characters meaning lose their order.

Answer (score 0):

as per the requirement of "Papua New Guinea" use regex `\w[^,]+$.*`

```
String str = "94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w[^,]+$.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

System.out.println(matcher.find()?matcher.group():"Not Found");
```